# How to split a csv data file which is vertical and merge horizontally using python script

Tags: python, csv, data-manipulation

I am new to python and I want to write a script that manipulates a csv file obtained from Tera Term. The file has 3 column and I want to split 3rd column at every 160th line and stack them horizontally. The data is too long to do it manually and I believe python would be the best way to approach this.
Below table is the input.csv file look like

[image: Input Table]

I want the output file to be in following format
[image: output.csv]

Below is my python script,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
""" Parses USS Template project UART data (src.csv) and store result in out.csv"""
import re
import struct
import sys

def decode_file(file_in_name, file_out_name):
    # Open File Input and Output Files
    input_file = open(file_in_name, "r")
    target_file = open(file_out_name, "w")
    # Iterate through the data 
    count=0
    for line in input_file:
        # Remove New Line
        line = line.rstrip("/n")
        # Remove Spaces in front
        line = line.lstrip(" ")
        # Remove White space and tabs
        pattern = re.compile(r"\s+")
        clean_line = re.sub(pattern, " ", line)
        # Split the line by spaces
        line_list = clean_line.split(",")
        #write 3rd column
        if count<160:
           target_file.write(line_list[0]+",")
           target_file.write(line_list[1]+",")
           target_file.write(line_list[2] +"\n")
        else if count%160==0:
                #Goto first row and next column of the target file and write next 160 lines of 3rd column and continue till the end
        count=count+1
        # Close Files
    input_file.close()
    target_file.close()
    print("Successfully Generated: \n", file_out_name)
    return
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print ("Invalid input.")
    else:
        # Parse the USS Template project src input file and store result in
        # output csv
        decode_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

How can I go to first line and next column of the target file for every 160th line and write the value from 3rd column. Could anyone please direct me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

some keywords, since I'm confident you can find the answer and tutorials online: numpy, csv, transpose 2D array.

For example:

read csv file ->

https://pythonspot.com/reading-csv-files-in-python/

transpose 2D arrays ->

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

edit: Of course, you can do it without numpy, but it is best with numpy if you have large datas.